# How to make <xsd:key> apply only to the current scope?

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

Ok so, basically what I currently have is:

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns="test"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="test"
            elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:complexType name="fields">
        <xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:element name="text">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="group">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="fields" type="fields"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:element name="root">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="fields" type="fields" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:key name="fieldId">
                        <xsd:selector xpath=".//*"/>
                        <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
                    </xsd:key>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="test">

    <fields>
        <text id="asd"/>
        <text id="sdf"/>
        <group id="dfg">
            <fields>
                <text id="asd"/>
                <text id="sdf"/>
            </fields>
        </group>
    </fields>

</root>
```

Clearly XML is not valid according to XSD since there are ID's that are duplicate, but the problem is, that I want the id's to be validated only in their own scope, in other words this should fail:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="test">

    <fields>
        <text id="asd"/>
        <text id="asd"/>
    </fields>

</root>
```

while this should pass:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="test">

    <fields>
        <text id="asd"/>
        <group id="sdf">
            <fields>
                <text id="asd"/>
            </fields>
        </group>
    </fields>

</root>
```

Just to make it clear, I'm planning to prepend the parent ID to the child ID when parsing the XML and therefore I don't care about nested ID's being duplicates while their not in the same scope since I want to be able to achieve similar results to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="test">

    <fields>
        <group id="eventA_time">
            <fields>
                <text id="hour"/>
                <text id="minute"/>
                <text id="second"/>
            </fields>
        </group>
        <group id="eventB_time">
            <fields>
                <text id="hour"/>
                <text id="minute"/>
                <text id="second"/>
            </fields>
        </group>
    </fields>

</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I haven't got an answer that would work exactly as I needed, I'll just post a version version of XSD that worked as I need while still looking kind of ugly due to some parts being duplicated:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns="test"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="test"
            elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:complexType name="fields">
        <xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:element name="text">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="group">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="fields" type="fields" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xsd:key name="innerFieldId">
                                <xsd:selector xpath="*"/>
                                <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
                            </xsd:key>
                        </xsd:element>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:element name="root">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="fields" type="fields" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:key name="fieldId">
                        <xsd:selector xpath="*"/>
                        <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
                    </xsd:key>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to search relative:

**CHANGE:**

```
<xsd:key name="fieldId">
    <xsd:selector xpath=".//*"/>
    <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
</xsd:key>
```

**TO:**

```
<xsd:key name="fieldId">
    <xsd:selector xpath="*"/>
    <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
</xsd:key>
```

Comment: It does make the outer scope work, but it seems like the child elements are not validated at all making so when I repeat in the first fields scope (http://pastebin.com/tvgKL2w0) the same ID it's treated as invalid (which is good), but when I repeat the same ID in the child group (http://pastebin.com/xEbn7mFe), it's treated as valid which is not exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the selector from `.//*` to `*` (or `text`).